# How to add address as cvitem?

Tags: moderncv

I am using moderncv classic and I want to achieve something similar to this, where the address is part of a section. 
However, I want it to have at the left side like it is default in moderncv classic style. 
I tried several ways, but none were quite good:
Linebreaks inside moderncv did not work and creating an empty item with only the address info (e.g. street) as description was not properly aligned.

So, how do I get the address as a cventry field?

[image: CV with address]

Comment: After I cleaned the temporary created files, it seems to work now with an   `cvitem{}{Loong Name}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, after deleting the tempoary files, it works now with the following

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        %
 \moderncvstyle{classic}         
 \moderncvcolor{blue}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
 \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
 \name{John}{Doe}
 \title{Resume}     
 \begin{document}
 \makecvtitle
 \section{Personal Data}
 \cvitem{Address}{Looong Name}
 \cvitem{}{Long Street}
 \cvitem{}{Postal Code + City}
 \cvitem{Telephone}{+12~(123)~1234569}
 \end{document}
```